# Will charged water ions sprayed onto plants keep insects off?

Tags: biochemistry, entomology, biophysics, pest-control, bioinorganic-chemistry

I had stumbled on an article about a Dutch firm that devised an irrigation system that used mist of ionized water droplets that they claim keeps insects away from the plants.  This break through would revolutionize eco-friendly organic agriculture by reducing the need for insecticides.  They also claim nitrates are also formed by the process and embedded in the mist to supply nitrate fertilizers as well.  Thus eliminating the need for extra chemical fertilizers.

I tried to find the site again and the company but not coming up on search.
Are there any merits to these claims?  How would such a process or device work?